# OrientDB Edge label whitespace replaced with +

Tags: orientdb

I am new with OrientDB. Just having a question around edge label. When I store the edge label with whitespaces, the whitespaces are replaced with '+' sign.

I guess this is normal? or did I do something wrong?

It would be helpful if someone can explain to me why OrientDB doesn't like whitespace for edge labels.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you working in Studio or Java API?

Comment: I am using Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the Studio and viewing the graph, the label on edge is the java class name that extends E. Since it is the name of a class you can not create it with withespace inside.
[image]

If this is your need to mark an edge with a "label" that contains whitespace, you could do so:

- Create the class E (for example TestE)
- Enter a property (myLabel)
- Connect two vertices with this Edge and enter the property value (for example 'text of my label')
- With the following query you will see the two connected vertices, and properties that you have created on the arc.

Query:

```
select out.name, myLabel, in.name, @class from 
(select expand(inE()) from Persona) where @class = "TestE"
```

This is the result:
[image]

**EDIT 1**

In this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/oCFD4xj0Zzw) there is a note relating to the naming convention, however since OrientDB is developed in Java, i think it is the official naming convention of the Java language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's interesting how edge label is a class. Although I am using Java API not the studio but I guess this is the reason why OrientDB by replaces the whitespaces with plus sign in order to create the class name.

Comment: Also, is there any documentation that details the rules about edge label's naming convention?

Comment: I edited the answer adding the answer to your question about the documentation.